# Positioning Facebook like buttons alongside images

Tags: css, facebook, image

http://jsfiddle.net/ADLrh/

Hopefully you can see what I'm after. The three 'fillers' on the top row have sunk, upsetting the pyramid-like formation. Any idea what's causing this?

EDIT: I should also add that the method I go for needs to be flexible because potentially any filler could be a like button and the actual pyramid is quite a lot bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, like Guy suggested, you're going to want to use the `float` property rather than `display: inline-block`, because `inline-block` is pretty finicky for vertical alignment when using different types of elements next to each other, with whitespace between them.

However, to keep the "pyramid" form, you'll want to wrap the buttons in another div that IS set to `display: inline-block`, to allow the whole row to center in the current parent div.

Like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/syd8L/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. One last question - how do I restore the padding between the button and the filler to its right? Adding padding to the button produces adverse results...

Comment: Here, this is with the styles cleaned up a bit more, see if that "restores" it: http://jsfiddle.net/syd8L/2/

Comment: Oh, in IE8, I see what you're referring to: Facebook replaces the styles on the button with a background image that is actually a larger width, which explains the extra padding I saw when I first viewed it in Chrome (and then removed). This now looks fine in IE8, though does appear to have extra padding in Chrome, which is Facebook's fault: http://jsfiddle.net/syd8L/3/

Comment: I'm using Chrome too. That extra padding must be what's throwing me. The image is 51x24, which is what the button is supposed to be. Is there a universal fix that takes that into account? The like button is still slightly lopsided (in your example part of the right hand side is missing)

Comment: Ah, well, you can adjust that yourself until it fits by changing the `width` of the iFrame in the CSS. I set it to 51px here: http://jsfiddle.net/syd8L/5/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the white spaces between the HTML elements. This is not however the case where you should use `display: inline-block;`. Analyze [this example](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/). You could use `float` instead, then you wouldn't need to worry about whitespaces between HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add some relative positioning to the buttons on the first row, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ADLrh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `display: inline-block`, you should also add `vertical-align: top`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ADLrh/2/